# Unicode error while converting RDD to Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting the following error when I run show method on the data frame.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o14904.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 23450.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 23450.0 (TID 120652, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/i854319/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
    process()
  File "/Users/i854319/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/Users/i854319/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-8-b76896bc4e43>", line 320, in <lambda>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-5: ordinal not in range(128)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:156)
```

When I only fetch 12 rows, it doesn't throw the error.

```
jpsa_rf.features_df.show(12)
+------------+--------------------+
|Feature_name|    Importance_value|
+------------+--------------------+
| competitive|0.019380017988201638|
|         new|0.012416277407924172|
|self-reliant|0.009044388916918005|
|     related|0.008968947484358822|
|      retail|0.008729510712416655|
|      sales,|0.007680271475590303|
|        work|0.007548541044789985|
| performance|0.007209008630295571|
|    superior|0.007065626808393139|
|     license|0.006436001036918034|
|    industry|0.006416712169788629|
|      record|0.006227581067732823|
+------------+--------------------+
only showing top 12 rows
```

But when I do .show(15) I get the error.

I created this data frame as below: it is basically a data frame of features with the their importance values from a Random Forest Model

```
vocab=np.array(self.cvModel.bestModel.stages[3].vocabulary)
        if est_name=="rf":
            feature_importance=self.cvModel.bestModel.stages[5].featureImportances.toArray()
            argsort_feature_indices=feature_importance.argsort()[::-1]
        elif est_name=="blr":
            feature_importance=self.cvModel.bestModel.stages[5].coefficients.toArray()
            argsort_feature_indices=abs(feature_importance).argsort()[::-1]
        # Sort the features importance array in descending order and get the indices

        feature_names=vocab[argsort_feature_indices]

        self.features_df=sc.parallelize(zip(feature_names,feature_importance[argsort_feature_indices])).\
        map(lambda x: (str(x[0]),float(x[1]))).toDF(["Feature_name","Importance_value"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using Python 2. The problem at hand is most likely the `str(x[0])` part in your `df.map`. It seems `x[0]` refers to a unicode string and the `str` is supposed to convert it to a bytestring. It does so however by implicitly assuming an ASCII encoding, which will only work for plain english text.

This is not how things are supposed to be done.

The short answer is: Change `str(x[0])` to `x[0].encode('utf-8')`.

The long answer can be found e.g. [here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) or [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).